# Conversion failed when converting dictionary to number

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Both of 'ee.Dictionary.values().getNumber()' and'ee.Dictionary.getNumber()' are failed

Code

```
function tempCalulate2000_2004(image){
var temp=image.select('LST_Day_1km').reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
geometry: Lake2000_2004,
scale:30,
maxPixels: 1e13
}).values();
var date=image.date().format('YYYY'+'-'+'MM'+'-'+'dd')
return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(temp).gt(273), 
image.set('temp',temp).set('date',date), ee.Image(0))}
```

error
List (Error)
Collection.reduceColumns: Error in map(ID=2004_01_17):
Number.gt, argument 'left': Invalid type.
Expected type: Number.
Actual type: List.
Actual value: [278.19383714655214].

using ee.Dictionary.getNumber()

```
function tempCalulate2000_2004(image){
var temp=image.select('LST_Day_1km').reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
geometry: Lake2000_2004,
scale:30,
maxPixels: 1e13
}).getNumber('LST_Day_1km');
var date=image.date().format('YYYY'+'-'+'MM'+'-'+'dd')
return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(temp).gt(273), 
image.set('temp',temp).set('date',date), ee.Image(0))}
```

new error
List (Error)
Collection.reduceColumns: Error in map(ID=2002_02_26):
Number.gt: Parameter 'left' is required.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood clearly your issue, you don't need to use 'reduceRegion' method for selecting parts of images with temperatures greater than 273 ºK in 'MODIS/006/MOD11A1' product. On the other hand, your **return** doesn't work because you are mixing numbers and images methods in a not appropriate way.

Following [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/539e348c0e4f6667649bef1ac292ff70) works by using a threshold of 298 instead of 273 (I used 298 for watching mask behavior in USA territory).

```
var Lake2000_2004 = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-104.0432724585647, 34.42959938980137],
          [-104.0432724585647, 33.84764010788944],
          [-103.2522568335647, 33.84764010788944],
          [-103.2522568335647, 34.42959938980137]]], null, false);

Map.centerObject(Lake2000_2004);

function prepImg(image) {
  var date = image.get('system:time_start');
  return ee.Image(image).multiply(0.02).set('system:time_start', date);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2004-01-01'))
                  .map(prepImg);

var landSurfaceTemperature = dataset.select('LST_Day_1km');

print(landSurfaceTemperature);

//Map.addLayer(landSurfaceTemperature.mean().clip(Lake2000_2004));

var tempImg = landSurfaceTemperature.map(function (image){
  var temp = image.select('LST_Day_1km').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: Lake2000_2004,
    scale:30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  }).values();

  var date = image.date().format('YYYY'+'-'+'MM'+'-'+'dd');
  
  //return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(temp).gt(273), 
  //          image.set('temp',temp).set('date',date), ee.Image(0))
  
  return image.updateMask(image.gt(298).eq(1))
              .set('date', date);

});

print(tempImg);

var tempImg_lst = tempImg.toList(tempImg.size());

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["LST_Day_1km"],
                     "min":298.02,
                     "max":300.62,
                     "gamma":1};

Map.addLayer(ee.Image(tempImg_lst.get(2)).clip(Lake2000_2004), imageVisParam);
```

After running it in GEE code editor, I got following result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! My goal is to get the average temperature of a selected area of a single image. I found the reason for the error: null values were not filtered out. In addition, I found that the single image range of this product is global, so in reduceRegion, is the geometry valid?